# How the following java script arrow function identify the index?

Tags: javascript, callback, arrow-functions

The following script transpose a given array in two ways. 
Both do the job, only I do not understand how the second method works.

```
//Define array
var a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];

//Transpose
var b = a[0].map((col, i) => a.map(row => row[i]));
console.log(b); //[ [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 5 ], [ 3, 6 ] ]

//Transpose using callback
b = a[0].map(callbBackFunction(a));
b = a[0].map(callbBackFunction()); //Correction
console.log(b); //[ [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 5 ], [ 3, 6 ] ]

function callbBackFunction() {        
    return (col, ind) => a.map(row => row[ind]);
}
```

These two methods are essentially identical only in the second time extracting the map callBack function was extracted to an external function.

What I don't understand is how variable `ind` in the `callBackFunction` is assigned with its value, as `callBackFunction` is not defined nor called with parameters.

The map functions calls the provided callback, in this case `callBackFunction`, with the current index (as well as the current item and the mapped array), but `callBackFunction` does not have parameters to accept this value(s).

what am i missing?

*edit: 
this was a typo:

> b = a[0].map(callbBackFunction());

rather than

> b = a[0].map(callbBackFunction(a));

Comment: `callbBackFunction` doesn't have any parameters, so `callbBackFunction(a)` might as well be `callbBackFunction()`. The inner function there uses the global `a` regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`callbBackFunction` is executed before `map` runs and is actually returning the function inside of it. That function doesn't execute until `map` is fired, in which you can see it has the same function signature as `map`'s callback.

```
function callbBackFunction() {        
    return (col, ind) => a.map(row => row[ind]);
}
```

Here's an example to help this make a bit more sense:

```
const fn1 = () => {
     return (name) => "hello " + name
}

// fn1 returns the name func
const nameFn = fn1()

// we can now call nameFn with an argument
nameFn('OJNSim') // hello OJNSim
```

You can learn more about **closures** here: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-closure-b2f0d2152b36